# Fast combination of elements in a list in R

Tags: r, rcpp

I am trying to find an efficient way to extract all pairwise combinations of vectors stored in a list. The purpose of this code is to compute the average correlation of all possible pairwise combinations of data vector, within a resampling procedure with 100000 iterations.

```
 # Data simulation
 set.seed(90)
 dummy_data <- matrix(runif(21120),33,640)
 dummy_list <- vector("list",length = 33)
 for (i in 1:33){
  dummy_list[[i]] <- dummy_data[i,]
 }
```

The solution I have found so far is:

```
n_iter <- 100000
cor_out <- vector("numeric",length = n_iter)

# For each iteration
for (z in 1:n_iter){

 # Randomly shuffle the data 
 dummy_list_resample <- lapply(dummy_list, FUN = function(x){sample(x,size = 640)})  
 all_ind <- length(dummy_list_resample)
 combs <- combn(all_ind,2)

 # Initialize list for storing all pairwise observations
 out_list <- vector("list",length(dim(combs)[2]))

 # For each pairwise combination
 for(i in 1:dim(combs)[2]){

   # Identify and extract the data for each pair of subject
   pair <- combs[,i]
   vec1 <- dummy_list_resample[[pair[1]]]
   vec2 <- dummy_list_resample[[pair[2]]]

   out_list[[i]] <- cbind(vec1,vec2)
 }

 # Compute correlation for each pairwise combination
 # and store the average value
 cor_iter <- sapply(out_list, FUN = function(x){cor(x[,1],x[,2])})
 cor_out[z] <- mean(cor_iter)
}
```

which I found rather inefficient because it is really slow (~12 h of computing)

Is there a way to avoid the loop? I am aware of Rcpp as way to speed up iterations, but unfortunately I am not familiar with C++. Any hint or example would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your example doesn't work - please check

Comment: I can't run your code because of undefined variables. Could you be more specific and/or give us a workable code to understand your expected output.

Comment: You might want to use the reprex  to prepare a *repr*oducible *ex*ample. http://reprex.tidyverse.org

Comment: You probably do not need that structure as here you copy each vector many times whereas you could access them when needed. Though if they are needed like that as inputs for some function you cannot modify, then you can't avoid the loop. Maybe run the loop in parallel with `parallel::mclapply`

Comment: Do you really need it to be a list of matrix with two columns?

Comment: I edited the post, so now it should be more clear the whole algorithm that I am trying to implement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can concatenate into a matrix, and the `cor` function takes in a matrix and calculates the pairwise correlation of all columns.

Your original approach:

```
list_cor <- function(seed=1) {
  set.seed(seed)
  dummy_list_resample <- lapply(dummy_list, FUN = function(x){sample(x,size = 640)})  
  all_ind <- length(dummy_list_resample)
  combs <- combn(all_ind,2)
  # Initialize list for storing all pairwise observations
  out_list <- vector("list",length(dim(combs)[2]))

  # For each pairwise combination
  for(i in 1:dim(combs)[2]){

    # Identify and extract the data for each pair of subject
    pair <- combs[,i]
    vec1 <- dummy_list_resample[[pair[1]]]
    vec2 <- dummy_list_resample[[pair[2]]]

    out_list[[i]] <- cbind(vec1,vec2)
  }

  # Compute correlation for each pairwise combination
  # and store the average value
  cor_iter <- sapply(out_list, FUN = function(x){cor(x[,1],x[,2])})
  mean(cor_iter)
}
```

Matrix approach:

```
mat_cor <- function(seed=1) {
  set.seed(seed)
  dummy_list_resample <- lapply(dummy_list, FUN = function(x){sample(x,size = 640)})  
  dummy_mat <- do.call(cbind, dummy_list_resample)
  cmat <- cor(dummy_mat)
  mean(cmat[lower.tri(cmat)])
}
```

Speed test:

```
library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(sapply(1:10, mat_cor), sapply(1:10, list_cor), times=10)

Unit: milliseconds
                   expr      min        lq      mean    median        uq       max neval cld
  sapply(1:10, mat_cor)  17.7916  19.00319  20.43652  20.68327  21.89248  22.72629    10  a 
 sapply(1:10, list_cor) 609.1673 622.57560 631.03171 628.26800 633.77480 673.58373    10   b
```

A speed up of ~31.5 times faster.

You can check the results are the same (there is a very small irrelevant difference due to floating point accuracy):

```
> mat_cor(1)
[1] 3.210217e-05
> list_cor(1)
[1] 3.210217e-05
```

If you still need more speed up after this, I suggest next looking into the `parallel` package.